# How to cancel search highlight in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I search something in Eclipse, the search items stay highlighted for some time. How do I remove this after I have found what I was looking for?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Remove your matches in the search view, that will remove the highlighting. I.e., click the button with the two X's in the search view.

If you cannot see that view, navigate to window -> show view -> Search

Comment: Of course, this effectively removes this search result from your search history... would be nice if you could disable the highlighting without losing the search results.

Comment: Note: Unlike what the tooltip implies, this does NOT affect your code. This just removes the matches from your search view. I've been searching for nonsense to clean this field for months before seeing this answer.

Answer (score 10):

AFIAK, the search result view has a toolbar button to clear the search results. This removes the highlighting in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is to run a search that will yield no results. For example file search, containing text - leave this field empty, files - some stupid extension like ".qwe".

For people concerned that https://stackoverflow.com/a/3545215/6012102 removes search results from history.

Select the search from history, press "Run the current search again" (2 rotating arrows icon). This will run the search and you will get all the results back (this brings back the text highlight as well unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

Disable Preferences->General->Text Editors->Annotations->Search Results->Text as.

Comment: This is the correct answer but the path needs a modern update: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Search Results -> Text As

Answer (score 0):

For a single instance, delete the line and undo it: <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>. This is faster than the other answers, and worked when they failed (for some buggy JSP I had).